# How To Use 'hasFile & 'file' or Equivalents When Utilizing '->only' on Request Object in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, request, arrow-functions

For fun I am trying to figure out different ways of doing things in PHP & Laravel (the version of Laravel I am using is 5.8.37) and I am having trouble when I use the 'only' arrow function (`->only`) on a request object variable.

For example, if I do the following to store only certain fields from my request like so:

`$imageRequest = ($request->only('image_file', 'filename'));`

This ends up working out well to get the two inputs/data I require, but the result is stored in an array, which is where the problem I am trying to understand how to overcome arises.

After storing just the values I need, I would like to pass `$imageRequest` to a function, and in that function I would like to check if `$imageRequest->hasFile`, as well as accessing the file from it like so:

```php
if($imageRequest->hasFile('image_file')){
...
$image = $imageRequest->file('image_file');
...

}
```

I have tried to convert the results of the `->only` array to an object but I am still unable to utilize `->hasFile` or `->file`.  I know that these arrow functions are meant to be used with request objects.

Is it possible to achieve what I am trying to do with `->only` (limiting what inputs/data I choose to include) but maintaining the functionality of `->hasFile` and `->file`?

Comment: i guess $request->only() meaning $request->inputs() and hasFile for $request->files()

Comment: just pass the request to your function/method